# Integrating Node API with wso2is

Tags: node.js, authentication, wso2, single-sign-on, wso2-identity-server

**Integrating Node API with wso2is**

I am new to wso2is. I have already developed rest API's in node. I have three different server or service.Now i want to perform single sign on functionality using wso2is. but, i am confused how to integrate my API's with wso2is server. I have already installed wso2is server locally. so, anyone can guide be or give direction where to start or give any reference.

Comment: Can you give a try on WSO2 IS quick start guide - https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Quick+Start+Guide . It has a Single Sign On sample

Answer (score 0):

One easy option is to use "OpenID connect".

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/openid-client. 
You can configure the "OpenID connect" in WSO2 IS with [Configuring+OAuth2-OpenID+Connect+Single-Sign-On](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/Configuring+OAuth2-OpenID+Connect+Single-Sign-On)

Copy the "client ID", "Secret" to your Node app. Configure the redirect URL properly.

Also it is better to treat the client as "Allow without client secret" and "PKCE".